# Inject ChunkContext instance in Partitioner in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement where i need to use some values provided in the chunkcontext object to be used in my MultiresourcePartitioner.

How can i inject the same in the partitioner.

The syntax for the partitioner is

```
public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize){
        logger.info("start"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    ......................................
.........................................
}
```

I want to have the instance of the chunkcontext in this method.How will i be able to do it ?

Comment: chunkContext is available when the chunks are processed, partitioner runs long before that, question is, what do you want to achieve with those values

Comment: i am logging errors in a custom database , so some of the parameters like jobid,jobname, starttime i access from the context to store in the database.

Comment: is it ok for you to store that before or after a specific resource is processed? if yes, check http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#stepExecutionListener

Comment: When the partitioner throws exception it is logged into the spring batch tables with all the batch details. I wanted to do the same , but in my own custom DB. I am searcging for APIs to do the same but not able to find it.

Comment: Why not use a `StepExecutionListener` with your chunked step? The `afterStep` method will have access to job name, start time, etc. via the Step and Job execution contexts, which you can use for any custom DB calls in the event of a failure.